# How can I save files from Mac folder and/or URL into a specific ios app's folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, storage

My app reads an specific file extension type to use as resource, which I have some examples in a "data" custom folder inside the xcode project. I need to save others files of this extension inside this custom folder that comes from internet or a mac folder (if the ios device is connected to mac). How can i do it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to save other files in project bundle when app is running?

Comment: @PayalManiyar If it's possible, the core of the problem is this: i read a file, and use it to render/get info. I got some examples inside the bundle, but how would I do it in case the user wants to use a file that it's in his mac document folder for example

Comment: @PayalManiyar Do you have any insight about it?